# Hovering over a selected path on chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a donut chart that I want to use, which is based on [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbhall88/b2504f8f3e384de4ff2b9dfa60f325e2).

I'm trying to create a function, when a user hovers over a certain path of the donut chart, the stroke color appears.

Nevertheless, I tried to edit a portion of the code but somehow the `"mouseover"` and `"mouseout"` handlers are ignored (not working)? I tried researching the Internet, but I couldn't find a solution.

Below is a portion of the code:

```
var path =
  svg.select('.slices')
  .datum(data)
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(pie)
  .enter().append('path')
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
    return colour(d.data[category]);
  })
  .attr('d', arc)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log("mouseOver");
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d) {

    console.log("mouseOver");
  });
```

Comment: That's because the events you add are being overridden by the code on the line `d3.selectAll('.labelName text, .slices path').call(toolTip);`. Have you tried commenting this line out or taking out `.slices path` from this line? Here's a fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/FMqAHXv17dlyDvkbNZrJ?p=preview

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help. Upon running the code,however, the tooltip that shows the values in the middle of the pie chart has disappeared. I actually want the chart's tooltip to stay consistent as I hover over each path. How can I do this?